# Querying on StrFields with large values returns no documents in Solr 4.4

Tags: string, solr, solrj, solr4

I'm having trouble querying on a StrField with a large value (say 70k characters). I'm using Solr 4.4 and have documents with a string type:

```
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
```

and field:

```
<dynamicField name="someFieldName_*" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

Note that it's stored, in case that matters.

Across my documents, the length of the value in this StrField can be up to ~70k characters or more.

The query I'm trying is `someFieldName_1:*`. If `someFieldName_1` has values with length < 32,767 characters, then it works fine and I get back various documents with values in that field.

However, if I query `someFieldName_2:*` and `someFieldName_2` has values with length >= 32,767, I don't get back any documents. Even though I *know* that many documents have a value in `someFieldName_2`.

I know this because I query `*:*` and see documents with (large) values in `someFieldName_2`.

So is there some type of limit to the length of strings in a StrField that I can query against? 32,767 = 2^15 is mighty suspicious =)

Comment: Do you have  LimitTokenCountFilterFactory configured in your solrconfig.xml.  <!-- maxFieldLength was removed in 4.0. To get similar behavior, include a 
         LimitTokenCountFilterFactory in your fieldType definition. E.g. 
     <filter class="solr.LimitTokenCountFilterFactory" maxTokenCount="10000"/>

Comment: I'm afraid that is bug or a "hidden" feature, I remember seeing bug reports about native string type limitations, but none are on "todo" list. Is there any reason for not using solr.TextField?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yonik answered this question on the Solr user mailing list with, "I believe that's the maximum size of an indexed token...". So it seems like the behavior is somewhat expected.

However, another user has opened up a bug report about the lack of errors, "i'll open a bug to figure out why we aren't generating an error for this at index time, but the behavior at query time looks correct..."